# How to get the star in A1?

Tags: the-talos-principle

While there's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ca2qIRqiZ0) showing how to get the star when you've started a new game, I don't know how to get the star afterwards. The video shows a hidden switch which I flipped as well, but then there's a barrier which required a jammer to open. However, I can't find one. When trying to go back to where you've started at the beginning of the game, there doesn't seem to a way to get back far enough to reach a jammer. There doesn't seem to be a way to pass the turret. So, how do I get jam the barrier at the star?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you're facing the turret, on your left will be a ladder hidden behind foliage. Use that ladder and follow the walkthrough as usual.

Here's a video demonstrating how to get the star without starting a new game